# how to calibrate a working star map to provide jump coordinates and executable jump data

Tags: navigation

so, my question for today is:
how are coordinating points going to be used in star maps for navigating and space jumps?  I know that jumping is possible. I have actually seen a jump.   but the nav maps aren't going to be like our gps satellites are using now.  no google maps to tell us how to get somewhere.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question. I'm not sure what you mean by "jumps".  I assume you mean some kind of teleportation or instantaneous transport.  If so, that puts this question outside the scope of Astronomy. If not, please clarify.

Comment: Are you talking about this in relevance to space jumps?

Comment: The [International Celestial Reference System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Celestial_Reference_System) uses distant extra-galactic radio sources, mostly [quasars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasar), as reference points, with the Solar System's barycenter as the origin. Alternatively, a [Voyager Golden Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_Golden_Record) uses a pulsar map to indicate the position of Earth. So, pulsars and objects like quasars could be used as reference points in a science fiction world where FTL jumps (which I assume you're talking about) are possible

Comment: *"I have actually seen a jump."* I don't believe you. Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence, but you've supplied zero evidence.

Comment: However, you may be interested in the related questions on Worldbuilding.SE, eg https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/91713